# Python ctypes addressof CFuncType

Tags: python, ctypes

Related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032470/python-ctypes-callback-function-to-swig)

How can I get the address (acctual function pointer) to a CFuncType object? addressof() does not report the correct address.

C code:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)
int addr(int (*func)())
{
    int r = (int)func;
    return r;
}
```

Python code:

```
def test():
  return 42

t = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)
f = t(test)

print addressof(f)
print dll.addr(f)
```

Output:

```
7030864
3411932
```

trying to call *(7030864) from C causes a crash, but calling *(3411932) works as expected. What's wrong with addressof()?

Comment: `CFUNCTYPE` is already a pointer, so `addressof()` returns the address where this pointer is stored, not address of function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cast(f, c_void_p)` gets the correct address from within python